# How do I generate an SSL certificate? How to access a page with invalid certificate in FF3?

Tags: firefox, ssl-certificate

I am not able to access localhost https pages in firefox3. It gave the error

> 'Can't connect securely because the SSL protocol has been disabled.
>   (Error code: ssl_error_ssl_disabled)'

I enabled all the SSL2 related preferences through about:config and the error changed to

> 'Data Transfer Error
>   The browser connected successfully, but the connection was interrupted while transferring information.  Please try again.'

The first error seems most likely due to a invalid certificate but can't figure out the second...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick way to create a self-signed certificate using openssl:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out /etc/apache2/cert.pem -keyout /etc/apache2/cert.pem -subj '/C=US/ST=Yourstate/L=Yourcity/O=Your Company, Inc./OU=Development/CN=your.vhostname.com/emailAddress=youremail@example.com'
```

(It's better to create a CA certificate separately and use that to create a certificate to use; apache complains to the error log when you use a self-signed certificate like above.
But I don't have a recipe handy for doing that.)

Then in your apache configuration (separately for each virtual host if needed), say:

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/cert.pem
```

and make sure mod_ssl is enabled.

You may be able to debug your problems using curl:

```
$ curl -sSvk https://your.vhostname.com 2>&1 | less
```

Answer (score 1):

What web server serves the pages? Is it IIS or Apache? 
Did you try to access these pages with other browsers? Answering the questions will give a clue if problems is in browser or web server.

[Here is good link how to create SSL ceritificates](http://blogs.technet.com/jhoward/archive/2005/02/02/365323.aspx)

Comment: It is a IBM Http server and the pages come up in IE.